# Python Banner Grabber/port scanner provides uncompleted results

Tags: python, port-scanning

I wrote this (below) Port Scanner/Banner Grabber that provides uncompleted results.

If I run it against metasploitable machine on Virtual Box, it returns all open ports and their banners. All seems okay!

If I run it against an online machine (kenobi from tryhackme) it returns:

> [+] Scan results for:10.10.124.162
>
> [+]22/tcp open:SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.7
>
> [+]21/tcp open:220 ProFTPD 1.3.5 Server (ProFTPD Default Installation)
> [10.10.124.162]

I know the port 80, 111 are open, but I don't understand why my code ignores them and doesn't work properly.

Generally speaking I notice that nmap provides very different result, but my aim is not to invent hot water, simply to understand and write basic programs.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from socket import * 
from threading import *

print ("Basic Port Scanner and Banner Grabbing\n")

def connScan(tgtHost, tgtPort):
    try:
        sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.connect((tgtHost, tgtPort))
        banner = sock.recv(2048)
        banner = banner.decode('utf-8')
        print ("[+]" + str(tgtPort) +"/tcp open:" + banner )
    except:
        pass
    finally:
        sock.close()


def portScan(tgtHost):
    """Run the Port Scan selecting by domain name or IP"""
    try:
        tgtIP = gethostbyname(tgtHost)
    except:
        print ("Can't Resolve Target host %s" % tgtHost)
    try:
        tgtName = gethostbyaddr(tgtIP)
        print ("[+] Scan results for: " + tgtName [0])
    except:
        print ("[+] Scan results for:" + tgtIP)

    setdefaulttimeout(2)
    for tgtPort in range (1, 65535):
       # Thread launch a separate flow of instruction that running separately
        t = Thread(target=connScan, args=(tgtHost, int(tgtPort)))
        t.start()


def main():
    """ask for input"""
    tgtHost = input("Insert the host IP Target: ")
    portScan(tgtHost)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The main program ends while most of threads haven't finished yet. Try removing the thread and just call connScan() function directly on each target port in the loop otherwise you need to keep track of all the threads and only exit when all threads are done.